# A script to copy one sheet to various spreadsheets in a specific folder in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I have a sheet which I need to copy to hundreds of spreadsheets in a given folder in Google Drive. I am just beginning with script and I do not know how to proceed because the script below just gives me an error. Thanks.

```
function myFunction() {
var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = source.getSheets()[0];
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('TEST FOR SCRIPT');
var contents = folder.getFiles();
for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
file = contents[i];  
}
sheet.copyTo(contents).setName('ANSWERS');
}
```

Comment: You can run each line of code, line by line, with the debugger.  [Google Documentation - Debugger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)

Comment: how about using the Copy Folder Add-on: http://scripts.edlisten.com/copy-folder

Comment: @BjornBehrendt I did not understand your comment. The problem I have is to copy a sheet to other spreadsheets, not to multiply folders. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was given this answer by someone within a community in Google+ and it works:

```
function copyToSheets() {
var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = source.getSheets()[1];

var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('ID');
var firstFolder = folders.next();
var folderFiles = firstFolder.getFiles();
var thisFile;

while (folderFiles.hasNext()) {
  thisFile = folderFiles.next();
  var currentSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(thisFile.getId());
  sheet.copyTo(currentSS);
  currentSS.getSheets()[currentSS.getSheets().length-1].setName('NAME');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('TEST FOR SCRIPT');
```

returns a [FolderIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator).  Even if you only have one folder by that name, the `getFoldersByName()` method returns an object, that you can't use the `getFiles()` method on directly.  The `getFiles()` method works on the Files Class.  It is not available to the Folder Iterator.  After you get the Folder Iterator, you must use the `next()` method to get the first (and probably only) folder in the object.

```
function getAllFilesInFolder() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = source.getSheets()[0];
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Folder Name Here');
  var firstFolder = folders.next();
  var folderFiles = firstFolder.getFiles();
  var thisFile;

  while (folderFiles.hasNext()) {
    thisFile = folderFiles.next();
    Logger.log(thisFile.getName());
 };
};
```

And also use `hasNext()` to loop through the files.  There doesn't seem to be an `length` property of the Files object.

Comment: Thanks @sandygood, but as I mentioned before, because of my ignorance in code, I do not know how to proceed with what you sent. Could you please finish the code so that others may find the complete answer and just be able to copy the code? What do I put at the end of what you sent me so that it finally copies the sheet to the other spreadsheets? Thanks.

Comment: Being more specific, if I just add sheet.copyTo(thisFile).setName('ANSWERS'); at the end of what you sent me, it tells me "Cannot find method copyTo(File)."